# Tortoise SVN commit loading forever

Tags: tortoisesvn, commit

When I want to commit files it takes ages for the loading of files to commit - what I mean is I click right in the folder, choose commit and the windows pops out fast but its loading files like 20 minutes even though there is for example just 1 file changed.

Reinstall - didnt help